# Find previous element in Ruby array Enumerable Enumerator

Tags: ruby

I have an array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

If I have an element in the array, I can find the next element in the array via the 
`a[0].next`

Is there a method that I can use to find the previous element 
`a[1].previous` or `a[1].before` such that the result is

`#=> 1`

I Googled around a bit and it seems as if most other similar questions involve a loop which I don't want to do. I also checked out the Ruby docs of [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) & [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html) and couldn't seem to find one.

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> a[0].next #=> 2
>> a[2].previous
NoMethodError: undefined method `previous' for 3:Fixnum
    from (irb):14
    from /Users/Lois/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
>> a[2].before
NoMethodError: undefined method `before' for 3:Fixnum
    from (irb):15
    from /Users/Lois/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `a[0].next` does NOT do what you think. Try it on this array `a = [10, 42, 23]`

Comment: Also, do not post pictures, post text from those pictures.

Comment: Oh man... lol. Thanks for clarifying on that @sergio. Ok, so there are no methods that do the two things I want to do then?

Comment: Nope, no such methods. An element has no concept of "a collection it's in". It might not be in any. And it might be in 10 collections at once.

Comment: Everyone else is correct that you're actually calling [`Integer#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-next) and it's not doing what you think, but for completeness, the opposite is [`Integer#pred`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-pred)

Comment: i don't understand your question. If you have an index like `a[0]`, you can simply call `a[1]`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

If you have an array:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Then calling `a[1]` will return the object `2`, and there's nothing special about that value, it's without context once you've retrieved it. As such, calling `next` on it will always yield `3` because that's what [`Integer#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-next) does.

In order to navigate through that array you need an iterator of some sort, like [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html):

```
e = a.each
```

Now you can do what you want:

```
e.next
# => 1
e.next
# => 2
```

Note that this interface isn't as flexible as you're expecting. You can call `next` to advance, or `rewind` to go back to the beginning, but there's no `previous`. Ruby doesn't have what other languages term as bi-directional iterators, but you might be able to extend this class to add the functions you need if you're feeling brave.

Answer (score 1):

I always end up whipping up something like this.

This approach, of course, isn't limited to `Array`s - I didn't want to make it an `EnumerableScanner`, however, as some enumerations maintain complex state (think of a fibonacci sequence).

```rb
class ArrayScanner
  attr_reader :index, :array

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
    @index = 0
  end

  def next
    raise StopIteration unless next?
    @array[@index += 1]
  end

  def peek
    raise StopIteration unless next?
    @array[@index + 1]
  end

  def next?
    @index + 1 != @array.size
  end

  def prev
    raise StopIteration unless prev?
    @array[@index -= 1]
  end

  def peek_prev
    raise StopIteration unless prev?
    @array[@index - 1]
  end

  def prev?
    @index - 1 >= 0
  end

  def eof?
    !next?
  end

  def bof?
    !prev?
  end

  def current
    @array[@index]
  end

  def current=(new_value)
    @array[@index] = new_value
  end

  def size
    @array.size
  end

  def pos
    @index
  end

  def rewind
    @index = 0
  end
end

a = ArrayScanner.new [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.current #=> 1
a.next    #=> 2
a.current #=> 2
a.prev    #=> 1
a.prev?   #=> false
a.bof?    #=> true
4.times { a.next }
a.eof?    #=> true
a.current #=> 5
```

The [crystal language](https://crystal-lang.org/) has a similar approach, with it's [Iterator](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.31.1/Iterator.html) module.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = 0
a[i]      #=> 1
a[i.next] #=> 2
a[i.pred] #=> 5

i = 1
s = 1
a[i]      #=> 2
a[i + s]  #=> 3
a[i - s]  #=> 1
```